# filter function in dplyr errors: object 'name' not found

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame in R like so called `UK_profiles`:

```
row.names   id     name
1   1   8131437     Profile
2   2   8131719     WolverineCompetition
3   4   8132011     www.vaseline.com
4   10  23265829    www.keepingskinamazing.co.uk
5   23  8042743     Mobile
6   24  8043312     Test
7   25  90914664    Join Our Core
8   26  45272695    UDF
9   27  50547829    apps.euro-bureau.eu/fairathon
10  28  50916438    www.benjerry.intashop.com/
11  44  83667343    All Web Site Data
12  45  84556272    UK
```

Using dplyr I wish to `filter` and delete rows with `grepl` using:

```
require(dplyr) 

UK_profiles.filtered <- filter(UK_profiles, !grepl("Rollup|Microsite|Mobile|Test|tset|Profile|Facebook|Unfiltered|returnurl", name))
```

However, I get an error saying:

> object 'name' not found.

I also get:

> In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion.

The object `'name'` is clearly in the dataframe. Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you load the `dplyr` package? There is a `filter` function by default in R, which gives exactly the same error. After loading `dplyr` (`library(dplyr)`), the `filter` function works.

Comment: Why dplyr? `UK_profiles[  !grepl("Rollup|Microsite|Mobile|Test|tset|Profile|Facebook|Unfiltered|returnurl", UK_profiles$names), ]`

Comment: Hi @Pascal. Yes I did load the package thankyou.

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, good point

Answer (score 78, accepted):

It does seem like you are getting the `stats::filter` function and not the `dplyr` one. To make sure you get the right one, use the notation `dplyr::filter`.

```
d = data.frame(x=1:10,
 name=c("foo","bar","baz","bar","bar","baz","fnord","qar","qux","quux"))

filter(d, !grepl("ar|ux", name))
Error in grepl("ar|ux", name) : object 'name' not found

dplyr::filter(d, !grepl("ar|ux", name))
  x  name
1 1   foo
2 3   baz
3 6   baz
4 7 fnord
```

You don't even need to do `library(dplyr)` for this to work - you do need `dplyr` installed though.

This works for functions from any package.

Comment: Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Because dplyr was given a function name matching one already in the R namespace.

Comment: @AlanD. If the package `dplyr` is not specified, the `filter` in the R base will be called and cause issue.

Answer (score 8):

To understand why this happens you can recreate the error quite straightforwardly by following these steps.

**Load dplyr**

Load `dplyr` into a new session with only default libraries loaded, `filter` will work as `dplyr` loaded after `stats`

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

filter(mtcars, mpg < 15)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> 2 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> 3 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> 4 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> 5 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
```

**Unload dplyr**

This causes the error as now trying to use `stats::filter`. By unloading `stats` we see another error that there is no function called `filter` found at all

```
detach("package:dplyr")  # Unload dplyr
filter(mtcars, mpg < 15)  # Using stats::filter
#> Error in filter(., mpg < 15): object 'mpg' not found

detach("package:stats")  # Unload stats

filter(mtcars, mpg < 15)    
#> Error in filter(., mpg < 15): could not find function "filter"
```

**Reload stats and dplyr**

Make sure to reload `dplyr` after `stats` and we see that the `dplyr` version of `filter` works again

```
library(stats)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> 
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

filter(mtcars, mpg < 15)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> 2 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> 3 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> 4 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> 5 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
```

Answer (score 2):

I reinstalled **rlang** package with restart session and it helped

Comment: how to reinstall rlang?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I unloaded tidyverse libraries and later tried to use `filter()` without first loading the tidyverse.

So the simple solution for me was to run this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
```

or this would have worked too

```r
library(dplyr)
```

and everything worked as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

It needs `dplyr::` before the code if you run `filter` as `dplyr`:

```r
dplyr::filter(UK_profiles, !grepl("Rollup|Microsite|Mobile|Test|tset|Profile|Facebook|Unfiltered|returnurl", name))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to both install the `dplyr` package with `install.packages("dplyr")` and then use the `library` command `library(dplyr)` to load `dplyr` into memory for use.
For example the `mtcars` dataset is a part of `dplyr`, if I only install `dplyr` and then enter `head(mtcars)` it doesn't find it. Once I use the `library` command it is found.