# 'filter' from dplyr package causes error message

Tags: r, dplyr

I run queries to ClickHouse database (connected with Rserver by RClickhouse package). Queries run smoothly unless I use `filter` function - which generates error message about wrong object type

Important detail: this problem appears only in Rstudio project that is located in common server folder. Same code works fine (without errors) in similar project that shares parent folder (/users/boris/) with R

```
    > a <- con %>% tbl("test_sample") %>% select(domain) %>% collect()
    > show(a)
    # A tibble: 140,000 x 1
       domain                         
     * <chr>                          
     1 allforchildren.ru

    > a <- con %>% tbl("test_sample") %>% filter(domain == "wildberries.ru") %>% collect()
      Error in storage.mode(x) <- "double" : 
         (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Any guesses what is the reason for such reaction on `filter` function?

P.S. session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.7.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] urltools_1.7.1    dplyr_0.7.6       getPass_0.2-2    
[4] DBI_1.0.0         RClickhouse_0.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18     dbplyr_1.2.2     crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.0
 [5] R6_2.2.2         magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.3.0     rlang_0.2.1     
 [9] rstudioapi_0.7   bindrcpp_0.2.2   tools_3.5.1      glue_1.3.0      
[13] triebeard_0.3.0  purrr_0.2.5      compiler_3.5.1   yaml_2.2.0      
[17] pkgconfig_2.0.1  bindr_0.1.1      tidyselect_0.2.4 tibble_1.4.2
```

Comment: Why do you have a space before the parentheses when you call `filter`? Try removing it

Comment: Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()`. This function is known to have namespace clashes with other packages, which also have a filter() function.

Comment: @camille, thanks for noticing this space - though I checked, it doesn't affect the outcom

Comment: @Thomas, I added sessionInfo() as P.S.

Comment: I think you're experiencing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267072/filter-function-in-dplyr-in-r-not-working

Comment: @Thomas, yes - direct notation dplyr::filter solved the issue
Though I'm still confused that the same command may provide different results depending in fact on the location of project files

Comment: It might be that packages are being attached to the search path in a different order - dplyr first then stats in one case, and the opposite in the other. Perhaps the server edition is running in `--vanilla` model. You can check `search()` on both to see which package is listed earlier, or just use `dplyr::filter()` in every case.

Comment: I checked search() - 'dplyr' is ahead of 'stats', at least under current session of the project that provided the error