# Why is my kable table producing this "no applicable method" error?

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, kableextra

I have searched, but prior discussions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267072/filter-function-in-dplyr-in-r-not-working)) unfortunately have not helped. I cannot diagnose the error in this problem. Fundamentally, I'm trying to exclude certain rows or columns from my table. However, my code:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)      

knitr::kable(mtcars, digits=3) %>%
  dplyr::filter(cyl == 6) %>% 
    kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

produces this error:

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
>   no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "knitr_kable"

I know from prior discussions that `dplyr` masks `filter` from `stats`, which is why I used the double colon `("::")` to specify the library I think I want. The fact that the error cites `filter_` (with the underscore) tells me that the problem is arising within `dplyr` or my understanding of it. `dplyr` is at version 0..8.0.1 and `knitr`is at version 1.22.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the right things in the wrong order--but you are on the right track. You need to manipulate your dataset before piping it into `kable`. Let me know if this helps and if you have any other questions!

```
library(kableExtra)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)      

mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 6) %>%
  kable(digits=3) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrew - you marvel! This completely works and solves my problem! Happy day!