# Why do I only receive "NA" for results when filtering a variable in my dataset?

Tags: r, filtering, resultset

I am trying to filter the `wooldridge` dataset `gpa1` so `job19` only shows observations where 19 hours were met. I ran the command

```
library(wooldridge)
filter(gpa1, job19 == 1)
```

to see all the instances where `job19 == 1`, and all the observations came up as `NA`.  Does anyone know why this would be the case?  I viewed the `gpa1` variable before-hand and `job19` is a dummy variable so all the observations are listed as either `1` or `0` so I should have some results, right?  I also tried to filter out instances where `job19 == 0`, but I got the same results.

Comment: Can you post all the code? Filter() is a funciton in more than one package. You might want to check which version of filter you are using, or (even better) quality it, with e.g. stats::filter() or dplyr::filter()

Comment: With `dplyr::filter(gpa1, job19 == 1)` I cannot reproduce any error. Vote to close as off-topic/not reproducible.

Comment: akrun, what do you mean by "class of the columns?"  I ran the code you suggested and it said that the job19 observation results were all integers, is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Jeremy Miles, I got an error trying to run the dplyr::filter() code, and the stats::filter() code produced all NAs again, thanks for the suggestion  though!

Comment: i think JeremyMiles is right.

Answer (score 0):

Econ465, simply load the packages and make the proper use of their functions.

```
library(wooldridge)
library(dplyr)
data("gpa1")
# View(gpa1)

df <- gpa1 %>% 
  dplyr::filter(job19 == 1) 
head(df, 10)
```

```
> head(df, 10)
   age soph junior senior senior5 male campus business engineer colGPA hsGPA ACT job19 job20 drive bike walk voluntr PC greek car siblings bgfriend
1   20    0      1      0       0    0      0        1        0    3.0   3.6  26     1     0     0    0    1       0  0     0   1        1        0
2   19    1      0      0       0    1      1        1        0    3.5   3.5  27     1     0     0    0    1       0  0     0   0        1        0
3   22    0      0      0       1    0      0        0        0    2.7   3.0  22     1     0     1    0    0       0  1     0   0        1        1
4   22    0      0      0       1    0      0        0        0    2.7   3.0  21     1     0     1    0    0       0  0     0   1        1        1
5   19    1      0      0       0    0      0        1        0    3.8   4.0  27     1     0     0    0    1       0  1     0   0        1        0
6   21    0      0      1       0    1      0        1        0    2.8   3.0  19     1     0     0    0    1       0  0     0   1        1        1
7   21    0      0      1       0    0      1        1        0    3.0   3.5  23     1     0     0    0    1       0  1     0   1        1        1
8   20    0      1      0       0    0      0        1        0    2.6   3.5  25     1     0     1    0    0       0  0     1   1        1        1
9   22    0      0      1       0    1      0        0        1    2.7   3.0  23     1     0     0    0    1       0  0     0   1        1        0
10  21    0      0      1       0    0      1        0        0    3.0   4.0  25     1     0     0    1    0       1  1     1   1        1        1
   clubs skipped alcohol gradMI fathcoll mothcoll
1      1     0.0    1.00      1        1        1
2      0     0.0    0.00      0        0        0
3      0     3.0    3.00      1        1        1
4      1     2.0    2.50      1        1        1
5      1     0.5    0.75      1        0        1
6      0     2.0    1.00      1        0        0
7      1     0.0    1.00      1        0        1
8      1     3.0    2.00      1        1        1
9      1     1.0    1.00      1        0        1
10     1     0.0    0.00      1        0        0
```

> See this link below.

[Filter function in dplyr in R not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267072/filter-function-in-dplyr-in-r-not-working)

Comment: `install.packages("dplyr")` or `install.packages("tidyverse")`

Comment: See: `?head`, `?View` and `?print` functions. You can to use `View(df)`, `print(df)`.

Comment: If you consider the answer as certain, could you check to accept the answer?