# what means this error in R, when previously it did not

Tags: r

I am working a R project, data is BRFSS2013. I have some data and plots, but now where I just working in others line, show a error in a line where previously it bring me information.

[image]

When delete this code, it start to show error, for example, in the code for doing the plot. What it happened, if I did not working in that line.

This previously to show that error.

file:///C:/Users/olga%20carvajal/Desktop/Adriana/Introduction_To_Probability_and_Data_with_R/intro_data_prob_project.html

Thank you.

Adriana

Comment: consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267072/filter-function-in-dplyr-errors

Comment: (1) Any "link" for us that starts with `file:///` or contains `C:` is almost certainly useless. Do you expect everybody on SO to have access to all files on your local computer? (2) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.